# Microsoft External Authentication using Oauth in ASP.NET 4.6; GetExternalLoginInfoAsync returns null in ExternalLoginCallback

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, owin

I sucessfully implemented Facebook and Google authentication but I'm struggling with the Microsoft OAuth.

AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync() returns null in ExternalLoginCallback.

Here is what I have in *Startup.Auth.cs*:

```
    MicrosoftAccountAuthenticationOptions microsoftOptions = new MicrosoftAccountAuthenticationOptions()
    {
        ClientId = "my-ms-ApplicationId",
        ClientSecret = "my-ms-Password/Public Key",
    };
    microsoftOptions.Scope.Add("openid");
    microsoftOptions.Scope.Add("email");
    app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(microsoftOptions);
```

I setup this route in *RouteConfig.cs*:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Microsoft API Sign-in",
        url: "signin-microsoft",
        defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "ExternalLoginCallbackRedirect" }
    );
```

and

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult ExternalLoginCallbackRedirect(string returnUrl)
{
    return RedirectPermanent("/Account/ExternalLoginCallback");
}
```

On the Microsoft API side, I created my application and selected a Web platform with "Allow Iimplicit Flow" and the redirect URL is

> https://localhost:44335/signin-microsoft

On Microsoft Graph Permissions I have Delegated Permissions *User.Read* and *User.ReadBasic.All*.

When I click on "Sign in with Microsoft" I am successfully redirected to Microsoft to select an account and when I click on the account I am coming back to my site in ExternalLoginCallback, and GetExternalLoginInfoAsync returns null.

I am using .NET 4.6.1 and using Microsoft.OWin 3.1.0

What am I missing?

Comment: I noticed there are Delegated Permissions for **openid** and **email**, but even with these permissions I get the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research on this issue on .NET 4.6 and not finding too much documentation and finding more documentation about .NET Core I decided to try to convert my application to .NET Core and it works fine.

In short, I have not been able to use Microsoft Authentication on .NET 4.6 as it **may not be** implemented (or badly documented) but Microsoft Authentication works fine on .NET Core 2.

Don't forget to add **openid** and **email** in your Microsoft app portal -> Graph Permissions -> Delegated Permissions.
And add the scopes in your code (in *Startup.cs*):

```
services.AddAuthentication().AddMicrosoftAccount(microsoftOptions =>
{
    microsoftOptions.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:ApplicationId"];
    microsoftOptions.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:Password"];
    microsoftOptions.Scope.Add("openid");
    microsoftOptions.Scope.Add("email");
});
```

Comment: You saved my day. This part was extremely important: "Don't forget to add openid and email in your Microsoft app portal -> Graph Permissions -> Delegated Permissions." but I added profile on the top of openid and email.  Curiously, I didn't have to add the scopes in the code.